# resize and positioning image not working

Tags: jquery

i am re sizing some overlay images on load according to the screensize of the user. But the problem is it does not work everytime it loads. if i refresh too many times it works once . dont know where the problem is as no errors coming too. i have checked in chrome and firefox developer tools also. here is my code can any one suggest what is wrong here.

```
(function($){ 
$(window).load(function() {
var Height=$(window).height(); // New height
var Width=$(window).width(); // New width
$('.content-container').css('background-size', Width + 'px' + ' ' + Height + 'px');
$('.weare_map').height(Height*.54);
$('.invent_div').height(Height*.4);
var top2= ($(window).scrollTop());
$('.invent_div img').css('top',top2*.4);
$('.weare_map.map1').css('top',top2*.3);
$('.weare_map.pixels').css('top',top2*.2);
$('.weare_map.wearefaces').css('top',top2*.05);
  $('.content').css('height',Height + 'px');

});

$(window).resize(function() {
  // This will execute whenever the window is resized

var Height=$(window).height(); // New height
var Width=$(window).width(); // New width
$('.content-container').css('background-size', Width + 'px' + ' ' + Height + 'px');
var overlayw=$('.content-container').width();
var overlayh=$('.content-container').height();
$('.weare_map').height(Height*.54);
$('.invent_div').height(Height*.4);
var top2= ($(window).scrollTop());
$('.invent_div img').css('top',top2*.4);
$('.weare_map.map1').css('top',top2*.3);
$('.weare_map.pixels').css('top',top2*.2);
$('.weare_map.wearefaces').css('top',top2*.05);
$('.overlay').css('background-size', overlayw + 'px' + ' ' + Height + 'px');
$('.content').css('height',Height + 'px');

});

        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please don't use `Uppercase` for variable names.

Comment: `$('.weare_map').height(Height*.54);` can (and should) be done in CSS: `.weare_map{height: 54%}`

Comment: i cant do it in css as its dynamic screensize i am taking for every type of screen size so i had used jquery please if u can suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: I can see a lot of code duplication. I suggest `$(window).on("load resize", function(){...`

Comment: Note that `$().load` for the event binding is deprecated. Use `on` (or `bind`, if you're using an old version).

Comment: tired that didnt worked the height and width is working fine but when i am trying to get top scroll value then it does not get the value i have to refresh many time to get it

Comment: What exactly isn't working then?

Comment: what i am tryin to get is `var top2= ($(window).scrollTop());` value from scrolltop so that i can use it to assign top margin to my images . but its not working

Comment: Since you're reacting to `scrollTop`, you might want to react to `scroll` events as well. Particularly Chrome is notable for automatically scrolling to the pre-refresh position a few miliseconds _after_ the page load.

Comment: What do you think `scrollTop` does?

Comment: it helps in getting scroll to top and can be used to get the top scroll to that image height . so that we can later on use it as a css image margin-top property

Comment: It gets the element's scrollbar position - the number of pixels from the element top to the element viewable area top. _This can change without the window resizing_.

Comment: It is rarely useful to relate the scrollbar position to `margin-top` - except to achieve a parallax effect (then you need to react to `scroll` events).

Comment: yes i am using a parallax effect . thats why i am using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you're trying to use the scrollbar position to achieve the parallax effect (the conversation confirms that) but you don't react to its changes (namely, `scrollTop` is pretty much always 0 on page load). You should listen to the [`scroll` events](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) as well. Try:

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(){
  var height=$(window).height(); // New height
  var width=$(window).width(); // New width
  ...

});
```

Alternately:

```
function recalculatePositions(){
  var Height=$(window).height(); // New height
  var Width=$(window).width(); // New width
  ...

}

$(window).on("load resize scroll", recalculatePositions);
  // $(window).load(function) has been deprecated
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works . thank you for helping me with explanation ::)